# Proving that a group is either cyclic or not-simple

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, group-actions, cyclic-groups, algebraic-combinatorics

This problem is from Chapter 7 of *Algebraic Combinatorics* by Richard p. Stanley:

Let $X$ be a finite set, and let $G$ be a subgroup of the symmetric group, $S_X$. Suppose that the number of orbits of $G$ acting on $n$-colorings of $X$ is given by the polynomial: $$f(n) = \frac{1}{a} (n^p + bn^{p-2} +  \cdots + (p-1)n)$$

where $p$ is prime.

Prove that $G$ is either a cyclic group or it is not a simple group (it gives the hint that a simple group only has two normal subgroups: $G$ and the identity).

So far, I have been able to show that $G$ has order $a$, $X$ has order $p$, $G$ has no transpositions, and that $G$ acts transitively on $X$.

Some of the main theorems/notes that come from this chapter are the following:

- Burnside's Lemma
- Given a group of permutations, $G$, of $X$, the number of inequivalent $n$-colorings of $X$ is:

$$\frac{1}{\#G} \sum_{\pi \in G} n^{c(\pi)}$$ where $c(\pi)$ is the number of cycles in $\pi$.

- Cycle indicators and cycle index polynomials
- Polya's Thorem of 1937
- The number of $n$-colored necklaces of length $\ell$ (where the set of symmetries is the cyclic group) is: $$\frac{1}{\ell} \sum_{d | \ell} \phi \left( \frac{\ell}{d} \right) n^d$$ where $\phi$ is the Euler Totient Function.
- The number of permutations $\pi \in S_{\ell}$ with $c_i$ cycles of length $i$ where $\sum_i ic_i = \ell$ is given by: $$\frac{ \ell}{ 1^{c_1} c_1! 2^{c_2} c_2! 3^{c_3} c_3! \cdots}$$

---

Some progress that I've made so far is recognizing that that in a transitive group action, the orbits induced by a normal subgruop will all have the same size. Thus, for any normal subgroup, $H$, in $G$, the orbits induced by $H \times X \rightarrow X$ will all have the same size.

I don't understand, however, how to relate this back to the polynomial that we are given. How do we prove that $G$ must have a normal subgroup (or that it is cyclic)?

Comment: Assume $a$ is the order of $G$ and $G$ is transitive as you say you have proved. Then if we assume $G$ is cyclic we would expect $f(n)$ to be the formula you mentioned for 'The number of -colored necklaces' of length $p$. The formulas certainly match if we let $b = \phi(\frac{p}{p-2})$ so we should believe that $G$ could be cyclic.

Comment: Can you show that  is prime? The polynomial $ \frac{1}{G} \sum_{g \in G} n^{c(g)} $ counts the number of $$-colourings of the action of $$. If $=||$ as you say, then the $(−1)$ term of $()$ implies there are exactly $(−1)$ elements of $$ with only $1$ cycle, i.e. cyclic permutations which move all points of $$. If $p$ were prime then these $(p-1)$ cycles of length $p$ would belong to the same cyclic subgroup of $G$, and this would be a normal subgroup since conjugates of $p$-cycles are also $p$-cycles and there are no other cycles of length $p$.

Comment: It is given that $p$ is prime so I guess that solves the problem. Putting it all together, could we say that the group of $(p-1)$ cycles of length $p$ forms a normal subgroup (unless this normal subgroup is the entire group, $G$). So, either $G$ has a normal subgroup and is not simple or it has to be that cyclic subgroup. Does that work?

Comment: If $p$ is prime then I think the argument you just described is correct.

I would write a proper answer but there are two things I have not been able to be rigorous about. (i) I don't know how you showed $a = |G|$; (ii) I made an assumption that $f(n)$ is the same polynomial in $n$ as the polynomial $\sum_{g \in G} n^{c(g)}$ after collecting terms which have the same power of $n$, but I'm not sure how to argue that these polynomials must be the same. (ii) is what allows us to say that there are exactly $(p-1)$ cycles of length $p$.